# GGit SSH Home wrong on windows

Tags: git, ssh

When i enter a push command, git points to wrong path for ssh key:

And i am running on windows.
This started to happen after i executed a command to try to fix ssh connection to other server and i dont find the command i had executed.

I already reinstalled git and nothing...

```
user@pcname MINGW64 /c/works/InovaWeb/inova-web (alteracoes_bruno)
$ git push
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
git@copadbhml: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The path is wrong, how can i fix this path? I think my git it's not point to local repo.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer to edited question:**

The error message says it all:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
```

The private key (from the adjective "private") can not be publicaly readable by anyone. In *NIX/Linux, the permissions are pretty obvious, the Windows really depends on what ssh is used and compiled in your git bundle magic, but I believe you will be able to tweak the permissions to avoid being *too open*.

**Original answer to the revision 1:**

This is not a ssh key path:

```
Could not create directory '/home/myuser/.ssh'
```

This is a path where `ssh` is trying to create a known_hosts file. If it can not write into your home directory, it is going to fail.

You should make your home directory writable to satisfy ssh.

Comment: Man, i'm using windows and my git is pointing to a linux path, this is the point. with GIT_SSH, i see that git is using his own ssh client and openssh, openssh is good.

Comment: @AgamenonD2 Do not significantly edit the question after it is asked and answered. You replaced the original log with a different one, but anyway, it is still easy enough to read the error message on your own and address the problem with sources as stackoverflow or google.